# Android O can't receive broadcast Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

In my application, I can receive `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` but can't receive `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` on **android O**. If I use **android N** or **android M** everything work fine.

I have register first broadcast in **AndroidManifest file** and second in **foreground service**, but none of them can receive `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`, only can receive `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`.

If anyone know how to fix it, please post your answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But I am still confused, because my phone not ask me to give the permission but work fine. Maybe a bug or feature of android O ?

Its a feature of Android O.

Previously, when you request a permission (`android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`) of a permission group (`PHONE`) and the user grants it, you are allowed to use any permission (`android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` etc.) of that permission group (`PHONE`) freely(without requesting to user again).

Now from Android O, even if your app already holds permission (`android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`) of a permission group(`PHONE`), you need to call `requestPermission` again for other permission (`android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`) of the same group. This will not prompt user to grant permission(`android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`) and the permission will automatically be granted if you already hold another permission (`android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`) of same permission group(`PHONE`).

Comment: Answer a bit confusing, any code snippets are welcome

Answer (score 4):

After some test, I fix it by add:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, requestCode)
```

But I am still confused, because my phone not ask me to give the permission but work fine. Maybe a bug or feature of android O ?

Comment: The permission is deprecated from Android Manifest but works programatically

Comment: Security reasons: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/#!?zippy_activeEl=sms-call-permissions#sms-call-permissions