# Android broadcast receiver of ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL not work if app process is not alive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am writing a small application to log outgoing calls.
It is based on broadcast intent ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.
I have a receiver registered in manifest and it works fine when my app process is alive.
However, if I reboot the device or the process got killed in background and without restart the process, the receiver does not work.

The app requested the necessary permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

And they are all granted.

And the receiver is registered as following:

`<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>`

I also checked that ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is in the ["Implicit Broadcast Exceptions"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) list, which means manifest registered receiver can still get called.
However, while it works fine when I start the app process, the receiver cannot be called if the app process is not alive.

I saw some [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151569/android-o-cant-receive-broadcast-intent-action-new-outgoing-call), but it is not my case.

Since Android Pie, the system becomes very aggressive on killing background processes. Especially on Google Pixel3 phone, almost all 3rd party applications are killed when you switch to camera app and navigate back.

I know there are methods to keep your process enduring in the background but I don't want so. I just want a clean implementation using this broadcast receiver.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You have to add `action` on your `intent-filter` `<action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: This only hide the problem for a while, if the process got killed in background by OOM, the problem will jump out again.

Comment: Are you calling `BroadcastReceiver` explicitly?

Comment: I never did that